# Axios - unknown number of multiple requests

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

Axios shows you can do multiple requests at the same time using:

```
function getUserAccount() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete
  }));
```

So it seems as though you need to know how many requests will be done. My problem is I do not know what or how many requests will be need to be done at any point.

So what I did was I created a function which will prepeare the requests:

```
createAxiosRequest(id) {
        return axios.get('https://someapi.com/' + id);
      }

    prepareRequests(numOfReq){
       var arr=[];
           for(var i = head ; i > 0; i--){
            arr[i] = createAxiosRequest(i);
            }
    }
```

So here I essentially return an array with all the requests. I then take this array and put it in:

```
axios.all(prepareRequests(13))
            .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {//What do I do here now?

            }))
```

And this is where my problem is. I do not know how many requests there will be so I cannot specify those "acct, perms, etc" responses beforehand. I am unsure then how to make it so that I can get all the requests and as well I want to still have the requests pass even though one or two failed, but this seems to run if all are successful only.

Comment: FYI, there's really little use for `axios.all` and `axios.spread`. You can just as easily use `Promise.all()`, eg `Promise.all(prepareRequests(13)).then(arrayOfResolvedData => { ... })`. There's even a PR to remove them from Axios ~ https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1042

Comment: Don't spread the results. Allow `.then()` to receive an array of results.